# Use an old laptop SATA DVD drive with a USB to SATA adapter?

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, dvd

I have an old laptop DVD drive, which I want to use as an external DVD drive. I'd like to use it with an adapter cable like this:

> [image: Photo]

Two questions:

- My DVD drive's sticker says that it needs 1.5 Amps power (Can this be right ?). This means that a USB port would not provide enough power, so this cable would not work, correct ?
- If I use a board from an Desktop external hard drive, which has an external power brick, that would work, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one probably does not work well due to the power problem you mentioned. Using a powered case will help as you know already.

Actually there are some other products which use "another" USB port purely for some additional power (say, they have two USB plugs) but I am in doubt about that - it may not be enough unlike hard disk drives.

Note that there are other products for laptop ODDs like this: 
http://image.dhgate.com/albu_841560118_00/1.0x0.jpg
(This is just an example and there are so many products like this)

This one fits better on laptop ODDs because of its shape and you don't have to buy or disassemble an external HDD case. But - not to mention, this one still needs a 5V AC adaptor anyway to operate your ODD stably.